# passing variable in URL for ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to understand a $.ajax call:

```
var url = "/api/followuser.php/"  + userID ;

$.ajax(url, { 'success': function(data) {
                    /do something
                     }
});
```

Thia ajax call is required to pass the variable 'userID' to the file '/api/followuser.php' to make a database query(php/Mysql).

I don't have access to  '/api/followuser.php' .

Can anyone help me figure out how to get the variable 'userID' from the URL in a php file to be used in a database query.( I know how to pass variable as 'data: userID,' in $.ajax and use it in a php file but i want to understand this particular example)

Comment: There is likely a mod_rewrite action on the server in question, which is an interpretation of a standard url, like the other answer from @tadman suggests.

check for `.htaccess` files if you're on apache, or other configuration files at the server level.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean `followuser.php?user_id=` instead? The slash is probably causing issues since that's interpreted as a directory by the server:

```
var url = "/api/followuser.php?user_id=" + userID;
```

Comment: Is this the only option because actually its written like url = base.api + "/" + userID ; and base.api = "/api/followuser.php";

Comment: That's highly irregular. Are you sure?

Comment: Yes. I don't know what you mean by 'highly irregular' but the "/" is definitely there instead of ?.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use GET method with ajax, to do this you can use next example

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/api/followuser.php",
     type: "GET",
     data: {variable: "valueofvariable"},
     success:  function(data) {
        console.log(data);
     }
});
```

so in your php file you can read the variable like this

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET["variable"])){
     echo $_GET["variable"];
     // if this works you should see in console 'valueofvariable'
    }

?>
```